# Question regarding the martingale property $E[X_{t}]=E[X_{0}]$ for all $t\ge 0$

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales

Given a stochastic process $\{X_{t}\}_{t\ge 0}$ and a filtration $\{\mathcal{H}_{t}\}_{t \ge 0}$ generated by $\{X_{t}\}_{t\ge 0}$ and if $X_{t}$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{H}_t$ we have the property

> $1)$ $E[X_{t}] =E[X_0]$ for all $t \ge 0$

the proof to this goes as follows using the property $E[X_{t}|\mathcal{H}_{s}]=X_{s}$ for $0 \le s \le t$ we have

> $E[X_{t}|\mathcal{H_{0}}]=X_0$

Then taking the expectation we get the desired result $(1)$.

My question is this what is stopping us doing the same for $\mathcal{H}_1$ and then deducing via the same method that $E[X_t] =E[X_1]$ for all $t \ge 1$ surely this contradicts $(1)$?

Comment: Why this contradicts (1) ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no contradiction. In fact, (1) implies that $E(X_t) = E(X_1)$ for all $t \geq 1$.

Comment: Well i guess the way I understand it from $(1)$ for a time say $t= 4$ we have $E[X_4]=E[X_{0}]$ whereas with my other definition we have $E[X_{4}] = E[X_{1}]$ which I don't see as equivalent, but I guess in this case we then have $E[X_{1}]=E[X_{0}]$ by $(1)$  so it works out

Comment: @seraphimk Right, I never claimed equivalence. I said, "(1) implies..."